# how to monitor how much memory, cpu is used by an instance of a program/script running in linux?

Tags: linux, ubuntu

I am on an ubuntu server, so I only have SSH terminal.

I would like to monitor how much memory and CPU something like

```
Jruby test.rb
```

is using.

Is it possible to monitor how much bandwith a process consumes? for example

```
rtorrent test.torrent
```

Comment: You might want to add "linux" as a tag, as this is not at all Ubuntu specific or server specific.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`top`

For starters.

`vmstat`
`procinfo -D`
`top`
`htop`
`pstree`

`ps -ef | grep test.rb`
will give some info too.

Yes, there are bandwidth monitors out there, `iotop` for one.

http://bhami.com/rosetta.html is always a decent starting point.

Comment: +1 for the Rosetta Stone for Unix !